# Ajax in php finding right div/class

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, class

```
<div id = 'eventcontainer' >
<span id = 'class'>
<?php

//Getting posts from DB

$event1 = mysql_query("SELECT post,date,memid FROM postaction WHERE memid = '$id' ORDER           BY date DESC LIMIT 5;");

while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($event1))
{

$event = $row1['post'];
$timeposted = $row1['date'];

$eventmemdata = mysql_query("SELECT id,firstname FROM users WHERE id = '$id' LIMIT 1");

while($rowaa = mysql_fetch_array($eventmemdata))
{
$name = $rowaa['firstname'];
 $eventlist = "$event <br> $name";
}


echo " <div id = 'eventer'> $timeposted <br>$eventlist</div> <input name='myBtn'            type='submit' value='increment' onClick='javascript:ajax_post();'>
<input name='lol' type='submit' value='dec' onClick='javascript:ajax_posta();'>
<div id = 'status'>lol</div>";
echo "<br>";

}
$('.eventcontainer.button').click(function() { 
$.post('javas.php', function(data) {
   $(this).parent('div').find('.status').html(data);
})
});
?>
</div>
</span>
```

I get an error when trying to run this code.
What i am trying to do is try to read which div/class the button is being clicked in, then perform the relative ajax/jquery functionality in that class only.

This is the Ajax/Jquery
function ajax_post(){

```
  $('.eventcontainer.button').click(function() { 
$.post('javas.php', function(data) {
   $(this).parent('div').find('.status').html(data);
})
});


hr.open("POST", url, true);

// Set content type header information for sending url encoded variables in the request
hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
// Access the onreadystatechange event for the XMLHttpRequest object
hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
        var return_data = hr.responseText;
        document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = return_data;
    }
}
// Send the data to PHP now... and wait for response to update the status div
hr.send("num=" + (++num)); // Actually execute the request
document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "processing...";

}
```

Comment: What error do you get? And what have you tried?

Comment: Why do you have jQuery inside of the PHP tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comments have noted, you should not have jQuery in your PHP tags.  Add some script script tags to your page's head, add a document.ready handler, then put the script in there.

Just note that once you accomplish this, you'll still have some problems since you're getting your `this` values mixed up.

```
$('.eventcontainer.button').click(function() { 
   $.post('javas.php', function(data) {
      $(this).parent('div').find('.status').html(data); 
   })
});
```

Once you hit the callback of your `$.post` call, `this` no longer is equal to the item you clicked on.  You'll need to save that element in a local variable before the call to post.

Something like

```
$('.eventcontainer.button').click(function() { 
    var self = this;
    $.post('javas.php', function(data) {
      $(self).parent('div').find('.status').html(data);
   })
});
```

Comment: should i put this in jquery tags not php?

Comment: @foshoeiyyy - I'm not a PHP guy, but I'm guessing this should **not** be in PHP tags.

Comment: @foshoeiyyy - put this code in your jQuery document.ready handler

Comment: @foshoeiyyy Only PHP should be in a PHP tag, unless you're echoing and/or printing something. You should have your javascript/jQuery in `<script>` tags.

Comment: @foshoeiyyy - add one.  Create a script tag in your header, and put one in there.  Check this out http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Introducing_$(document).ready()

Comment: there is no text on that page :9

Comment: @foshoeiyyy - second link on these search results  https://www.google.com/search?aq=f&gcx=c&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=jquery+document+ready

Comment: @foshoeiyyy - I don't follow.  Create the script tags, put in your document.ready handler, then add the script above into there.

Comment: I have a java script function that increments a variable on click of a button, however, this button is in many classes as it appears when the user makes a post (everytime the user makes a post the button appears below the post), however i need to determine whitch class (even though the names are the same their positions are not) the funciton needs to be echoed in.

Comment: @foshoeiyyy - I'm not sure - I'm not a PHP guy like I said, and it's hard to write out a question like this in the comments. I would recommend you start a new question for this